# Popup working on one browser but not another

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

Why would a popup work on one browser (works on firefox, firefox developer edition) but not another (not on Internet explorer, partially on Chrome) ? In some cases the popup would work on some pages of a website on a browser but going to another page on the site the same popup would not work.  The popup is in the footer

```
<a href="#" onclick="PopupCenter('/terms_conditions.aspx','','550','700')">Terms
                        &amp; Conditions</a>
```

any ideas ?

edit popup function :

```
<div class="footerTwoBox">
                    <ul class="footTwoLinks" style="width: 500px; float: left;">
                        <li><a href="/voucher">Your Voucher</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" onclick="PopupCenter('/privacy_policy.aspx','','550','700')">Privacy
                        Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<%=rootUrl %>/customer-care">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/press-room">Press Room</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" onclick="PopupCenter('/terms_conditions.aspx','','550','700')">Terms
                        & Conditions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/partners">Partners</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/careers">Careers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/customer-care/faq" target="_blank">FAQs</a></li>

                    </ul>
```

when you click on popup it just brings you to the top of the screen - with no popup.  If i go to firefox - i will get the popup in the middle of the screen... it must be some kind of broswer issue but I can't identify it.

popup function

```
function PopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
            //alert(w + "  " + h);
            var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
            var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
            var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
        }
```

Comment: What does your ``PopupCenter()`` function look like?

Comment: I posted the code.. it works on some browsers but not others

Comment: I was asking for the code of your ``PopupCenter()`` function, not the markup that calls it. What happens within that method?

Comment: forgot to add the popup function

Comment: if I take out pageURL and put in just URL I now get a popup (in Internet Explorer) but with a page not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to return `false` in your `onclick` handler. The link normally leads to the page you want it to show, while the popup script is called in the event handler. When you return `false` in your function, you prevent the browser from following the link.

This might or might not affect the behaviour of your browser, depending on the software you use. There is a very good write-up of this topic [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html), that covers most of the pitfalls.

Please try the following code:

```
function PopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
  left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
  top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
  targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

  if (window.focus) {
    targetWin.focus();
  }

  return false;
}
```

Then you can call it like this (notice the additional `return` keyword):

```
<a href="#" onclick="return PopupCenter('terms_conditions.aspx', '', '550', '700')">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
```

Complete demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Popup Demo</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function PopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
      left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
      top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
      targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

      if (window.focus) {
        targetWin.focus();
      }

      return false;
    }
    // -->
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="#" onclick="return PopupCenter('terms_conditions.aspx', '', '550', '700')">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with the above 
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Object expected

Comment: I can get it to run on the home page of internet explorer & Chrome but not subsequent pages. Why would that be ?

Comment: Does the popup not open on subsequent pages or does it open, but you get a page not found error? Are you including the JavaScript on subsequent pages as well or is it missing there, maybe?

Comment: nothing comes up in subsequent pages, no page not found or anything.  its the same javascript code for other pages but only works on the main page.

Comment: do you think its missing something from the top frame ?

Comment: I cannot tell without knowing the structure of your code, but I suppose you are not including the JavaScript code on subsequent pages correctly. Can you provide a link to your site or is it not online yet? Most browsers do have a console window, are there any error messages raised on subsequent pages? I suggest using a tool such as Opera Dragonfly or the Firebug plug-in for Firefox.

Comment: please visit http://www.darkrome.com/ - go to the bottom of the page and click on Privacy Policy and another link Terms & Conditions.  A popup should appear for these two.  Now go to another page in black (Rome, Vatican, Venice, Florence, Milan) at the top of page - once there try the same process, popup doesnt appear in IE or Chrome but does work in firefox and safari.  Error : Uncaught TypeError: window.open is not a function

Comment: Are you defining another variable called ``open`` in the scope of your subsequent pages? If you do, it is possible that ``open`` is overwritten and ``window.open()`` is no longer a valid function. For example, ``window.open = false; window.open('foobar');`` will raise such an error you described.

Comment: Yep, just checked your link. You are re-defining ``open``. There is a block of jQuery code right after a ``div`` called ``filterOptions1``. You should rename ``var open;`` to something like ``var myOpen;`` there, for example. The other variables, such as ``open1``, ``open2`` and ``open3`` are fine, they do not interfere with ``window.open()``.